# How to make HTTP REST calls to Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla1.5

I need to pull(in a mobile devise) some information from  Joomla through REST. Is that even possible? Is there any extension or something that can enable me to make HTTP REST calls to  Joomla ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this [extension](http://github.com/plexicloud/Plexicloud-JWS) or [this](http://relaxapi.com/) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to simplify the wrapping of the REST call.  I am making the assumption that you want the REST call to occur from the browser client.  If you want to call them from PHP you would need to use objects to make a web request to the REST endpoint.

Comment: I nedd to make a rest call form mobile devise to joomla. i find out to rest api https://github.com/techjoomla/Joomla-REST-API   and relaxapi   http://relaxapi.com/

Answer (score 0):

To make a REST call all you need to do (usually) is make an HTTP GET request and then consume the response, which is generally XML. There are often tools in a language that simplify that process, but that is the bare bones of it.

Comment: yap, I know that i need to make HTTP GET request, but problem is HOW to do in joomla?

Comment: You aren't doing it *in* Joomla are you, you are calling a Joomla web service *from* a mobile device.

Comment: thanks you and yes, I am trying to make a rest call from my mobile devise to joomla server.so, is there any suitable plugin available for that?

Comment: You don't need a plug-in you just need to make a GET request over HTTP (pointed at your Joomla url); I'd have thought that there would be an api for doing that in the language you are using since it is a pretty low level connectivity thing.

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow First, REST is not using only GET, it's using POST, PUT, DELETE etc. Second, Joomla is not a language, it's a CMS - like drupal and WP it interacts with the user via. UI while REST is an API.

Comment: @alfasin - If you had read any of what was written on this page you would realise that the OP wants to call a web service that already exists in Joomla from some unspecified mobile device. This device has a language that he needs to use to access the web service. In 99% of cases in the real world REST == HTTP GET; he probably just needs to make a request to the web service URL.

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow REST is not built into Joomla, but you can find a plugin. In REST the convention is to use POST if you create a new object, use PUT to update an existing object and use GET to fetch information about an object (and DELETE etc), so it doesn't make much sense to use only GET. To [*read more*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_services)

Comment: @alfasin In theory, theory and practice are the same. In practice, they are not.

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow This is NOT a theory, it's an integral part of the protocol.